# Error while deploying to Google App Engine ... it was working just fine a day ago

Tags: google-app-engine

Deploying worked just fine... until this morning:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [3] The following errors occurred while copying files to App Engine:
File https://storage.googleapis.com/xxxxxxxxxx.appspot.com/067c4141aeb3a82a8fa29f8c55b0b4b785fa24a3 failed with: Failed to save static file.


{
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ResourceInfo",
      "description": "Failed to save static file.",
      "resourceName": "https://storage.googleapis.com/staging.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.appspot.com/067c4141aeb3a82a8fa29f8c55b0b4b785fa24a3",
      "resourceType": "file"
    }
```

I have not really changed anything... just happened over night. I have also tried to remove the buckets from cloud storage, but no success. Any ideas?

Comment: ...happened to me too, I have tried the following(which didn't work for me):

- deleting the staging folder in storage
- setting gcloud config set app/use_appengine_api false
- upgrading gcloud sdk to latest version
- downgrading gcloud sdk to 299, 280, 260, 255

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be an incident:
https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/zall/20008

I just figured out a temporary workaround until they fix the issue:

1. Open the staging folder in storage,
2. search for the offending file(s) and delete it,
3. try deploy again,
4. repeat all steps until it successfully deploys

Answer (score 0):

I found an old incident report from 2015 [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35906400) that was similar and was patched then. But in that report someone mentioned that you could turn off the app engine api and the deployment would go through. I had this same issue today and tried that and it worked for me.

```
gcloud config set app/use_appengine_api false
```

Make sure you also star the [current issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/165694296) so they know other people are affected by it.